# There is a method in C# Distinct() to remove the duplicates, but its support Char datatype

Tags: c#

There is a method in C# Distinct() to remove the duplicates, but its support Char datatype.
how to use that in this code.

```
        {
            User allDepartment = new User();
            DataSet Department = allDepartment.GetAllDepartment();
            for (int i = 0; i < Department.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                String deptName = Department.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Depatment"].ToString().Trim();
                Dept_CBox.Items.Add(deptName);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Enumerable.Distinct<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Distinct__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) is a generic method, it supports *any* type. But you probably used it on a `string` which implements `IEnumerable<char>`, that's why you thought that it just supports chars. You have to use it on a collection of strings.

With a `DataSet` you can use `Linq-To-DataTable` which is a subset of `Linq-To-Objects`:

```
List<string> distinctDepartments = Department.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row.Field<string>("Depatment").Trim())
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
distinctDepartments.ForEach(deptName => Dept_CBox.Items.Add(deptName))
```